Is a thread-safe ledger insert possible in Postgres?
I am looking to create a ledger database table where each row insert is immutable and reflects the latest current table for an account. For example, if I had a table like this:
CREATE TABLE account_ledger
(
    id                 SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    account_id         BIGINT not null,
    transaction_id     VARCHAR(255),
    transaction_amount DECIMAL(10, 2) not NULL,
    current_balance    DECIMAL(10, 2) not null constraint positive_balance CHECK (current_balance >= 0)
);

I want to write a query that

selects the last (most current) row for the account id
Uses a default balance of "0" if no row exists
Inserts a new row reflecting the up to date balance being the transaction_amount + current_balance of the latest row

For example, if the state of the db was:
id  | acco_id | txn_id | txn_amount | cur_balance 
1   | 123     | A1     | 100        |100

an INSERT for a 10 credit would look like:
id  | acco_id | txn_id | txn_amount | cur_balance 
1   | 123     | A1     | 100        |100
2   | 123     | A2     | 10         |110

I was looking to write a query that would provide perfect consistent behavior to maintain data integrity. However, whatever query I attempt to run in a multi-threaded environment exhibits the kind of behavior that does not provide accurate results after several concurrent inserts.
Here is the latest query I am using:
WITH latest_data as (
  select
    wl.current_balance as latest_balance,
    wl.transaction_id as latest_transaction_id
    from account_ledger al
    where al.account_id = :accountId order by al.id desc limit 1 
    -- I've tried with and with out the row lock here
    for update
)
-- insert using values obtained from last row in latest_data
insert into account_ledger (account_id, transaction_id, transaction_amount, current_balance)
SELECT :accountId, :transactionId, :transactionAmount, coalesce (latest_data.latest_balance + :transactionAmount, :transactionAmount)
-- left join on potentially empty table from WITH clause above
from (select 1 as empty) e
left join latest_data on true
where :transactionAmount >= 0 or latest_data.latest_balance > ABS(:transactionAmount)
and (
 -- insert only when the latest_transaction_id equals the txn_id we obtained from above
    latest_data.latest_transaction_id is null or
    latest_data.latest_transaction_id = (select transaction_id from account_ledger cl where cl.account_id = :accountId order by cl.id desc limit 1)
)

If I do a series of 15 concurrent inserts of $10, I would expect a current_balance of $150. However, I instead get a value like $140 or even $130. I tried a variety of Isolation levels- Read uncommitted, read committed, and repeatable read and none have performed properly. Here is some example output with 15 concurrent inserts using Read_Uncommitted:
id | accoId|txnId | parentTxnId.  |txnAmount|balance 
790 263611  263611-3    new 10.00   10.00
792 263611  263611-5    263611-3    10.00   20.00
796 263611  263611-9    263611-5    10.00   30.00
798 263611  263611-7    263611-5    10.00   30.00
799 263611  263611-1    263611-7    10.00   40.00
800 263611  263611-11   263611-1    10.00   50.00
808 263611  263611-15   263611-11   10.00   60.00
815 263611  263611-13   263611-15   10.00   70.00
825 263611  263611-25   263611-17   10.00   110.00
826 263611  263611-29   263611-25   10.00   120.00
828 263611  263611-23   263611-29   10.00   130.00
819 263611  263611-19   263611-13   10.00   80.00
822 263611  263611-27   263611-19   10.00   90.00
824 263611  263611-17   263611-27   10.00   100.00
831 263611  263611-21   263611-23   10.00   140.00

Is there a way to get consistent results with the right isolation level and/or query? What is the best way to reason about inconsistent behavior with the current query?

Read Serializable.

Thread-safety is the wrong concept for databases. Instead, you have to look into the concept "isolation level".

Also note that your requirement is a well-known cause of database performance issues as it removes any concurrency for ledger transactions and easily leads to deadlocks. A solution I have seen before is that entries are put into a temporary state or separate queue (by multiple concurrent transactions) and a single process assigns the IDs and makes the entries permanent.

Yes, it can be done. You'll need to implement either optimistic or pessimistic locking. Both models will allow you to produce consistent results. The former can run into rollback for the transactions that "lose", while the latter will produce a bottleneck to let one transaction go at a time, while the others wait their turn to go in.

Serializable seems to be the best way to go, however I get: "ERROR: could not serialize access due to read/write dependencies among transactions
Detail: Reason code: Canceled on identification as a pivot, during commit attempt." despite having an index on account and only generating 1 message per account
